# Posting data to restify server from jsonClient is not working

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, restify

I am using restify, for TDD I am using mocha test framework. When I testing restify server from restify client with post method It is not working as expected.

My server code is below :

```
exports.post_user = function(req,res,next) {
var body = req.body;
if (!body.name || !body.email) {
    throw Error(JSON.stringify(body));
}
// Checking duplicate user before save user information into database
User.findOne({ email: body.email }, function (err, user) {
    if(err) { req.log.error(err); }
    if (!err && user != null) {
        res.send(user);
    } else {

        var user = new User({
            oauthID: Math.random(),
            name: body.name,
            email: body.email,
            created : Date.now()
        });

        // Profile not available then save information and return response
        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                req.log.error(err);
            } else {
                res.send(user);
            };
        });
    };
});
```

};

### and my test code is below

```
describe('core', function () {
describe('/admin/user', function () {
    it('POST with data', function (done) {
        var data = { 
            name: "aruljoth1i", 
            email: "aruljot1h1iparthiban@hotmail.com"
        };
        client.post('/admin/user', data, function (err, req, res, obj) {
            assert.equal(res.statusCode, 200,err);
            done();
        });
    });
});
});
```

when I am passing data as {name:'aruljothi'} it is working but as in the case of above json object it is not working. In server req.body is coming as {}.

### error

```
 2) Expecting 200 status code post /admin/user -> should return 200 status:
 Uncaught
 AssertionError: InternalServerError: {"message":"{}"}
```

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question, because sending an object `o` via restify's JsonClient resulted in an empty object `{}` on the server side.

To put it in code, if something like

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
app.listen(12345, function() {
    app.post('/', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
        res.end();
    })
})

var restify = require('restify');
var client = restify.createJsonClient({
        url: 'http://localhost:12345',
        version: '*',
    });

var some_object = {'foo': 'bar', '42': 23}
client.post('/', some_object, function(err, req, res, obj) {
});
```

gives you `{}` for `req.body`, make sure to also use the json bodyparser as middleware with

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Then it should finally give you the desired `{ '42': 23, foo: 'bar' }`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure @JOTHI this might solve your very issue, but I could not get my head around your example. If mine fits your case, feel free to copy it to your question.

Comment: Using restify's StringClient and sending `JSON.stringify(o)` as an alternative did not work as expected either, since it gave me the stringified version of `o` wrapped in an object looking something like `{ 'stringified o so to say': ''}`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the exact same problem using JSON.parse, for some reason var data is not getting recognized as an object.

```
describe('core', function () {
describe('/admin/user', function () {
    it('POST with data', function (done) {
        var data = { 
            name: "aruljoth1i", 
            email: "aruljot1h1iparthiban@hotmail.com"
        };
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        client.post('/admin/user', data, function (err, req, res, obj) {
            assert.equal(res.statusCode, 200,err);
            done();
        });
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

please check this url http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#JsonClient

```js
client.post('/foo', { hello: 'world' }, function(err, req, res, obj) {
  assert.ifError(err);
  console.log('%d -> %j', res.statusCode, res.headers);
  console.log('%j', obj);
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this documentation citation did not help me in any way, as it did not point out what @JOTHI was missing.